# Navigation drawer is not opening and toggleDrawer not found

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Trying to create drawer using React-Navigation.

Using `React Native 0.59`, Installed R`eact-Navigation 3.x`, has done linking react-`native link react-native-gesture-handler`.

Create routes using React-Navigation, called Route.js:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Settings: {
      screen: HomeScene,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',
        drawerIcon: () => (
          <Icon name="home" style={{ color: colors.white, fontSize: 24 }} type="Ionicons" />
        )
      }
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <GlobalSideMenu {...props} />
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScene,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    Drawer: {
      screen: Drawer,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Then in the header, drawer icon:

```
 <Button icon transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
      <Icon name={icon('menu')} type="Ionicons" style={styles.menuColor} />
 </Button>
```

It gives me error : toggleDrawer() is undefined.

Then I change it to :

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

Now, there is no error, but the drawer is not opening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually the case if you are attempting to open the drawer from outside the drawer navigator's set of screens.

`this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer` is only defined if you are in `Settings`, which I guess is not the case.

You can either rearrange the navigation so that the drawer is present on the screen you are calling `toggleDrawer` from, or you can navigate to `Settings` first.

```js
<Button
  icon 
  transparent 
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings');
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
  }}
>
  <Icon name={icon('menu')} type="Ionicons" style={styles.menuColor} />
</Button>
```

[Here is an example](https://snack.expo.io/@remeus/toggle-drawer-from-outside-drawer-navigator) to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

**first of all import
import { DrawerActions} from "@react-navigation/native";
then you can use it like**

```
<Button icon transparent 
  onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}>
     <Icon name={icon('menu')} type="Ionicons" style={styles.menuColor} />  </Button>



<Button icon transparent 
  onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}>
     <Icon name={icon('menu')} type="Ionicons" style={styles.menuColor} />  </Button>
```